# Displaying the system time in Empathy status

Tags: 10.04, empathy

Is it possible to display the current time in Empathy status, and perform simple manipulations, like

`currentTime + 10minutes`

I am using Lucid Lynx.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. I don't think it is. Have you had any success with that? I've been using Pidgin, and it doesn't work. I also tried Empathy, and no luck there either. I know that in iChat you *used* to be able to do that, but I haven't used a Mac in ages, and that doesn't answer your question. I don't think it's possible yet.

Comment: no, i havent tried t yet, because I dont know how to go about it :(

Comment: Alright, so you haven't figure out how to do it either. I'm pretty sure that there was a plugin that did it once upon a time.